# React/Next - Proper way to generate state with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to have react pull meta data from a list of files and display them within a div. The meta data is included in the text file and gathered using the front-matter module.

Still learning React and not sure what the correct way to create the state is.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React from 'react'
import frontMatter from 'front-matter'
import fs from 'fs'

import { getFileList } from '../util/utils'

export default class TheFileList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = getFileList('./static/filecontainer/').then((files) => {
      const linkParams = files.nameList.map((fileName, i) => {
        const content = fs.readFileSync(files.pathList[i], 'utf-8')
        const meta = frontMatter(content)
        return {
          name: fileName,
          title: meta.attributes.title,
          date: meta.attributes.date,
          description: meta.attributes.description,
        }
      })
      return {
        linkParams: linkParams
      }
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div id="fileDumpContainer">
          {
            this.state.linkParams.map((el, i) => {
              return (
                <div className="itemBlock">
                  <div id="nameBlock"><div id='tFileTitle'>{el.title}</div><div id='tFileDate'>{el.date}</div></div>
                  <div id="descriptBlock"><p className='tFileInfo'>{el.description}</p></div>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
  }
```

Util function:

```
import yaml from 'js-yaml'

export async function getFileList (dirname) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir (dirname, (error, files) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        files.reverse()
        resolve({
          pathList: files.map( el => dirname + el ),
          nameList: files.map( el => el.slice(0, -3) )
        })
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at TheFileList.render (C:\reactApp\.next\dist\components\TheFileList.js:84:31)
    at C:\reactApp\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:796:21
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (C:\reactApp\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:75:12)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (C:\reactApp\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:795:25)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (C:\reactApp\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:822:32)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (C:\reactApp\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:362:30)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (C:\reactApp\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:258:21)
    at Object.mountComponent (C:\reactApp\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactReconciler.js:46:35)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (C:\reactApp\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactMultiChild.js:238:44)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createContentMarkup (C:\reactApp\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactDOMComponent.js:653:32)
```

Comment: That error typically means that you're trying to create JSX with something invalid (for instance, misspelling "divv"), and doesn't really have to do with state. I'm curious if el.title/date/description are all strings - is, el.date an object?

Comment: el.date is a string "DD-MM-YYYY"

Comment: Think I fixed that issue, but now it cant find the state object.

Comment: No, it can't find linkParams on state. Try giving it a default value.

Comment: Think the issue is the Promise object is still pending when it tries to render, meaning it hasn't retrieved the list of files yet, is there a way to have it wait until the Promise object has finished before trying to render?

Comment: Not that I know of but setting a default value will at least mean that before the Promise has returned it's at least an empty array and doesn't throw that error. You can do that by putting `state = { linkParams: [] }` at the top level of the class (like, right after the constructor)

Comment: Well yeah that would stop the error but now the state is empty and never updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in a check in your render function to see if linkParams exists. Usually works for application level state (redux)

```js
 render () {
  if(!linkParams){
    return <div>Loading</div>
  } else {
    return (
      <div id="fileDumpContainer">
          {
            this.state.linkParams.map((el, i) => {
              return (
                <div className="itemBlock">
                  <div id="nameBlock"><div id='tFileTitle'>{el.title}</div><div id='tFileDate'>{el.date}</div></div>
                  <div id="descriptBlock"><p className='tFileInfo'>{el.description}</p></div>
                </div>
              )
            })  }
  }
```

Comment: I've tried that, it will display "loading" but wont update after.

Comment: Yea your component should be re-rendering after the state is updated. I believe the problem is that React doesn't have a built-in promise middleware. Since you're only using React, look into the react-promise package